# No page refresh while loading content from external pages + making links to each of those pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a navigation bar that loads content from external files without refreshing a page.

For example I have **index.php** with some special  that contains a content from **source_a.php** file. Using my navigation I can put into my  a content from **source_b.php** file and my **index.php** won't be reloaded.

Second part of the problem is that I need to create a links to different states of my **index.php**. I need to create links to **index.php** with **source_a.php** content or **index.php** with **source_b.php** content.

I found some tutorial that explains first part of my problem - it shows how to load external content from different pages into specific part of my page (source: https://johnmorrisonline.com/jquery-tutorial-ajax-load-content-with-no-page-refresh/).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        // Set trigger and container variables
        var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'),
            container = $('#content');

        // Fire on click
        trigger.on('click', function(){
          // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
          var $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('target');       

          // Load target page into container
          container.load(target + '.php');

          // Stop normal link behavior
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <?php include('home.php'); ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I still don't know if there is a method that allows to link to my **index.php** and at the same moment asks my **index.php** to load it's content from specific source (**source_d.php** instead of default **source_a.php**).

I've tried to use some variations of this:

```
<a href="index.php" data-target="home">Home</a>
```

...but nothing works.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with this code and should work if you have home.php and about.php existing, what message  do you get in your console?

Comment: No messages - this link simply doesn't work (nothing happens)

Comment: Add a console.log('triggered') at certain milestones in the code to help debug 
 trigger.on('click', function(){
  console.log('Link clicked')
})

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking about the same situation:)

I created <http://pxo.pl/test/index.php> that works well (I can switch between default "Home" and "About") but I'm trying to create separate page <http://pxo.pl/test/test.php> with links to both content versions ("Home" and "About") of index.php